# how to "crop" the result of canny edges detector

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a run the canny function and result look like this :

[image: canny Result]

I want to study the two regions "lines" so I want to crop them : like

[image: what I want to do]

by the way the "lines" can be on different positions:  like
[image: 3rd]

**I'm not asking for code but only for ideas how can I do it**
thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale your edge image down, and blur it, so that the edge pixels roughly form two thin continuous lines.
(you might want to do this scaling and blurring to the original image instead of the canny edge image, check what works best):

[image]

Then detect those lines with the [hough transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)

If your hough transform is reporting multiple matches per real line, you can either filter out matches that are close together, or scale your image down some more, or reduce the resolution parameters of the hough transform

Once you have the lines, remove every pixel with a distance-to-line > epsilon

---

Alternative suggestion:

[Morphological closing](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html): Dilate the edge image a few times, so that the edge pixels form a continuous blob. Erode the image a few times.

[Detect the contours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) of this blob with cv::findcontours.

Simplify the contour with cv::approxPolyDP.

If you only want a bounding contour for both lines, your a done. Otherwise go through each contour segment, find the right-angle turn between two long segments to find where to split the contour, if you want to separate the lines.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I didn't get what do you mean with the last line ?

Comment: i mean, `for each line: for each pixel (x,y) in the image: if distance(line,(x,y))> epsilon, set this pixel to black`, or white, or however you want to deal with pixels outside your roi